# must declare the scalar variable @

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

For some reason after defining my variables I am still getting the 'must declare the scalar variable' error..

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@user AND Password = @pass", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);

        int UserID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        return UserID < 0 ? -1 : UserID;
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception I am getting is: +  $exception {"Must declare the scalar variable \"@user\"."} System.Exception {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException}

Comment: Are user or pass coming in as null?  If they are, you might try passing in DBNull.Value instead.

Comment: I have checked the values and they are not null.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You should use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` if you connect to SQL Server - then you can use the **named** parameters. `OleDbCommand` only supports unnamed, positional `?` parameters ....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OleDb does not support named parameters. I presume this is what is causing the errors. Instead, within the SQL query, use `?` instead of the param name, and ensure the order of parameters added matches the order they appear in the query. 
so:

```
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID FROM tblUser WHERE Username=? AND Password = ?", conn))
{
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);

        int UserID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        return UserID < 0 ? -1 : UserID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following.  If a value is passed in as null, it will interpret it as missing.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@user AND Password = @pass", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user ?? DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass ?? DBNull.Value);

        int UserID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        return UserID < 0 ? -1 : UserID;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is value for both user and pass:    $exception {"Must declare the scalar variable \"@user\"."} System.Exception {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException}
  user "fdsafd" string
  pass "fdsafds" string

Answer (score 0):

Add Clear() to remove any parameters left over from the previous call. May this will work.

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear() 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
```